# How set calendar for Booking room hotel with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, mongoose

I build website for user can create their room. Room info includes calendar which is array like:

```
{"date":"15/02/2019","price":58,"note":"","price_fee":null} ,
{"date":"16/02/2019","price":58,"note":"","price_fee":null} ,
```

Frontend load info of room. It will get all date from today to next 2 year, which means that calendar is array having about 256 x 3 = 1098 values.

How can I store it with mongoose ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/), it provides a very straight-forward approach to creating your first schema and model.

Comment: Thank @ajbieber , but i know about mongoose. I am finding smart way to display data like that